# Prevent ace editor to center scroll on the cursor?

Tags: javascript, scroll, resize, ace-editor

The ace editor centers the view (scrolls horizontally) on the cursor even when the cursor is not outside the screen.

This happens after resize the ace editor container.

How to prevent ace editor to center on the cursor when it is not necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpKNvP) illustrates the problem.

To update the ace editor with the new width, use `editor.resize()`:

```
$(window).mouseup ()->
  if dragging
     editor.resize()
  dragging = false
  return
```